# What is difference between "as" and "is" operator in Kotlin?

Tags: casting, kotlin

In Java, I can write code like:

```
    void cast(A a)  {
    if(a  instanceof  Person)  {
        Person p = (Person) a;
    }
}
```

In Kotlin, what should I do?
Use `as` operator or `is` operator?

Answer (score 44):

`is X` is the equivalent of `instanceof X`

`foo as X` is the equivalent of `((X) foo)`

Additionally, Kotlin performs smart casting where possible, so no additional cast needed after you check the type using `is`:

```
open class Person : A() {
    val foo: Int = 42
}

open class A
```

and then:

```
if (p is Person) {
    println(p.foo) // look, no cast needed to access `foo`
}
```

Answer (score 42):

`is` is type **checking**. But Kotlin has smart cast which means you can use `a` like `Person` after type check.

```
if(a is Person) {    
    // a is now treated as Person
}
```

`as` is type **casting**. However, `as` is not recommended because it does not guarantee run-time safety. (You may pass a wrong object which cannot be detected at compiled time.)

Kotlin has a safe cast `as?`. If it cannot be casted, it will return null instead.

```
val p = a as? Person
p?.foo()
```

Comment: so if i always use 'is', that mean I can never use 'as' right? because IDE has smart cast

Comment: @ShawnPlus It depends on your use case. `as?` is better if you use the variable in multiple place. Smart cast only work within the bracket only.

Comment: can I see the any evidence reference of `as is not recommended`?

Comment: @Joshua smart cast works outside bracket, if inside bracket returns. Eg: `if(a !is String) return    //after this line, a is smart casted to string`

Comment: @wonsuc `ClassA as ClassB` will throw exception if cast is not possible. However `ClassA as? ClassB` will return `null` if cast is not possible

Comment: I think there are also some other case where `as?` is used vs `is`. Consider if I have a function that returns something `requireActivity()`. With `if (requireActivity() is MainActivity) { requireActivity().doSomething() }` is not valid (unable to smartcast) since it is a function call instead of property, in this case `requireActivity as? MainActivity` be come handy, since I can do `(requireActivity as? MainActivity)?.let { it.doSomething() }`

Answer (score 15):

"Kotlin in action" by Dmitry Jemerov and Svetlana Isakova has a good example of `as` and `is`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

is - To check if an object is of a certain type

Example:

```
if (obj is String) {
    print(obj.length)
}
```

as - To cast an object to a potential parent type

Example:

```
val x: String = y as String
val x: String? = y as String?
val x: String? = y as? String
```

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Answer (score 1):

As per Kotline official documents

1. Usually, the cast operator throws an exception if the cast is not possible. Thus, we call it unsafe. The unsafe cast in Kotlin is done by the infix operator as

   ```
   val x: String = y as String
   ```

Note that null cannot be cast to String as this type is not nullable, i.e. if y is null, the code above throws an exception. In order to match Java cast semantics we have to have nullable type at cast right hand side, like:

```
    val x: String? = y as String?
```

So here use **is** instead of as

```
 fun cast(a: A) {
    if (a is Person) {
        val p = a as Person
    }
}
```

Comment: we can use 'if' Statement to avoid ClassCastException,  why need 'as'? , I can always use 'if' and 'is'

Answer (score 1):

`as` is used for explicit type casting

```
val p = a as Person;
```

`is` is exactly the same as `instanceof` in Java. Which is used to check if an object is an instance of a class

```
if(a  is  Person)  {
      // a is an instance of Person
}
```

You can also used `!is` as is it not an object of a class

```
fun cast(a: A)  {
    if(a  is  Person)  {
        val p = a as Person;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

is Operator is checking datatype

but as is for casting to some type for example casting Int to String

Answer (score 0):

so

```
if(a is Person){
    a as Person
}else{
    null
}
```

equivalent

```
a as? Person
```

Is this answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can use **is** operator

```
fun cast(a:A){
    if (a is Person){
       var person = a
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add explanation to your code.

Answer (score 0):

**is**
checks that a value has a certain type.
is used in when expressions for the same purpose.

**as**
is used for type casts.
specifies an alias for an import.`

```
fun cast(a: A) {
if (a is Person) {
    val p = a as Person
} }
```