# What is the difference between "x is T" and "(x as? T) != null"?

Tags: kotlin, generics

In Kotlin, when writing a generic, non-inline function, `x is T` throws a compiler error due to type erasure.

```
fun <T> example(foo: Any, bar: T) {
    if (foo is T) { // compile error
        // ...
    }
}
```

However `x as? T` is perfectly fine, it seems (although does throw the usual "unchecked cast" warning). Why can't the compiler just replace `x is T` with `(x as? T) != null`? Is there a difference between these?

```
fun <T> example(foo: Any, bar: T) {
    if ((foo as? T) != null) { // no compile error
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `(foo as? T) != null` will always be true, because `T` is erased to `Any` and `foo` is always `Any`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in document [Generics type checks and casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#generics-type-checks-and-casts)

> Due to the type erasure, there is no general way to check whether an instance of a generic type was created with certain type arguments at runtime, and the compiler prohibits such is-checks such as ints is List or list is T (type parameter).

Explained why `is` is not allowed.
And

> ...
> The type arguments of generic function calls are also only checked at compile time. Inside the function bodies, the type parameters cannot be used for type checks, and type casts to type parameters (foo as T) are **unchecked**

state that `foo as? T` is unchecked, just like `foo as? Any`.

We can verify this by running below

```kotlin
public fun <T> asExample(foo: Any, bar: T): Boolean {
  if ((foo as? T) != null) { // no compile error
    return true
  }
  return false
}

public fun main() {
  println(asExample("A", "B"))
  println(asExample("A", 0))
}
```

Which will print

```
true
true
```

Related: [What is difference between "as" and "is" operator in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067302/what-is-difference-between-as-and-is-operator-in-kotlin)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I think there is a key difference between `foo as T` (mentioned in the docs explicitly) and `foo as? T`. You would not expect `foo as? T` to ever throw a `ClassCastException`, but in this case, it can. I just tested by adding a parameter `baz: (T) -> Boolean` and then using it in the body of the function like `baz(foo)` (smart cast) then calling it like `asExample(5, "", {it.isEmpty()})` and indeed I get a `ClassCastException`

Comment: I tried doing the same, but what I see the exception is thrown from `baz(foo)`, not from `(foo as? T)`. Which is expected as 5 has no `isEmpty` method. In our case, we should not perform `foo as T` or `foo as? T` as it is not really checking anything.

Comment: Me too, I guess then the actual cast is performed at `baz(foo)` not `foo as? T`. I never considered that smart cast is also a cast, I thought it was just like syntactic sugar. Also I thought smart cast is always a safe cast, but obviously here it is not.